# How to get hash values from array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Input:-

```
array = [{"name"=>"id", "value"=>"123"}, 
         {"name"=>"type", "value"=>"app"}, 
         {"name"=>"codes", "value"=>"12"}, 
         {"name"=>"codes", "value"=>"345"}, 
         {"name"=>"type", "value"=>"app1"}] 

sample_hash = {}
```

Function:-

```
array.map {|f| sample_hash[f["name"]] = sample_hash[f["value"]] }
```

Result:-

sample_hash

```
 => {"id"=>"123", "type"=>"app", "codes"=>"345"}
```

But i need expected result should be like below:-

sample_hash

```
 => {"id"=>"123", "type"=>["app","app1"], "codes"=>["12", "345"]}
```

How can i get my expected output?

Comment: Although it's not exactly what you've asked for, it will make you hash easier and nicer to work with if you have an array even for the keys that only have one value e.g. `"id" => ["123"]` - that way when getting values from the hash you won't have to check if you have got back a string or an array.

Comment: @mikej Agree with you. API consistency matters and helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize `sample_hash` using the `new {|hash, key| block }` Hash constructor to make the values in this hash be initialized to empty arrays by default.
This makes it easier in the second phase, where each value in the initial data set is appended to the array of values indexed under the corresponding "name":

```
sample_hash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
array.each { |f| sample_hash[f['name']] << f['value'] }
```

[Try it online](http://ideone.com/T4koPq)

Answer (score 1):

@w0lf is correct. Same, but different construct.

```
array.each_with_object({}) do |input_hash, result_hash|
  (result_hash[input_hash['name']] ||= []) << input_hash['value']
end
```

Answer (score 0):

See this :

```
array.inject({}) do |ret, a| 
    ret[a['name']] = ret[a['name']] ? [ret[a['name']], a['value']] : a['value']  
    ret
end
```

o/p : `{"id"=>"123", "type"=>["app", "app1"], "codes"=>["12", "345"]}`